# New document opens in a very small size, not full screen

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word-2010

When I open a new Word 2010 document it opens in a very small size, not full screen. I cannot get it to the full size so I can't read the font that I am typing as it is so small.

I have tried clicking on the top right corner to maximise but nothing happens. I have re-booted the computer but no change.

Must I remove Microsoft Word 2010 and re-load it?

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot to let us know what you are experiencing that could help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the bottom right of the window to make sure the zoom level is at 100%?

[image: Word 2010 Zoom Control]

Comment: Sounds like a good explaination of the problem.